# Inserting array values

Tags: arrays, postgresql

How do I write and execute a query which inserts array values using libpqxx?

```
INSERT INTO exampleTable(exampleArray[3]) VALUES('{1, 2, 3}');
```

This example code gives me:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'"
```

What is wrong? In PostgreSQL documentation I found that:

```
CREATE TABLE sal_emp (
name            text,
pay_by_quarter  integer[],
schedule        text[][]
);
```

...

```
INSERT INTO sal_emp
VALUES ('Bill',
'{10000, 10000, 10000, 10000}',
'{{"meeting", "lunch"}, {"training", "presentation"}}');
```

Comment: What is the type of `examplearray`?

Comment: @klin It is smallint but it does not matter

Comment: Of course this matters. Your query would be syntactically correct on a text array column .

Comment: @klin I know. I meant, there is no difference between types, which are used.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You should use a column name without an index to insert an array:

```
create table example(arr smallint[]);
insert into example(arr) values('{1, 2, 3}');
-- alternative syntax
-- insert into example(arr) values(array[1, 2, 3]);

select * from example;

   arr   
---------
 {1,2,3}
(1 row)
```

Use the column name with an index to access a single element of the array:

```
select arr[2] as "arr[2]"
from example;

 arr[2] 
--------
      2
(1 row)

update example set arr[2] = 10;
select * from example;

   arr    
----------
 {1,10,3}
(1 row)
```

You can use `arr[n]` in `INSERT` but this has special meaning. With this syntax you can create an array with one element indexed from the given number:

```
delete from example;
insert into example(arr[3]) values (1);
select * from example;

    arr    
-----------
 [3:3]={1}
(1 row)
```

As a result you have an array which lower bound is 3:

```
select arr[3] from example;
 arr 
-----
   1
(1 row)
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I tried "[]", "[3]", " ' " and without " ' " but I don't tried without "[]".

Comment: also you shall be able to execute this statement `INSERT INTO example(arr) VALUES (ARRAY[1,2,3])` (as another alternative to use if you don't have a string value)

Answer (score 28):

ref: https://ubiq.co/database-blog/how-to-insert-into-array-in-postgresql/

### A. use `ARRAY`

```sql
insert into employees (id, name, phone_numbers)
         values (1, ' John Doe', ARRAY ['9998765432','9991234567']);
```

// less nested quotes

### B. use `'{}'`

```sql
insert into employees (id, name, phone_numbers)
  values (2, ' Jim Doe', '{"9996587432","9891334567"}');
```

OR

```
insert into employees (id, name, phone_numbers)
  values (2, ' Jim Doe', '{9996587432,9891334567}');
```

// seems inner quotes `"` not necessary,
// number or string depends on column type.

Comment: For string arrays it's more readble to use **ARRAY**